# Embedded PayPal Login Button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

All,

I am trying to add a PayPal login button to my site based on https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/loginwithpaypal/integration/. Currently, I am using PayPal sandbox therefore I use the static AppID "APP-80W284485P519543T" (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/paypal-apis-getting-started-guide).

The following is my JavaScript code

```
        <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
    <script>
        paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
        login.render ({
            "appid": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
            "authend": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/",
            "scopes": "profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
            "containerid": "myContainer",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "returnurl": "http://localhost:3000/"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I run it, I got the error "Relying Party Validation error: client_id provided in the request does not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request."

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.

Create a seller in sandbox.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

go to the profile of the seller and check the client id under Log In with PayPal credentials, use it as your appid. I also used only "sandbox" as value of "authend"

The funny thing is that Log In with PayPal credentials not appeared to me until I had made the steps bellow and checked the profile again, I really dont know why:

login to www.sandbox.paypal.com with the creted seller accont

go to: 
profile->Request API credentials
Option 1 - PayPal API
Set up PayPal API credentials and permissions
Option 2 - Request API credentials to create your own API username and password.

Also, it only started working when I created a fake app in production...

The new sandbox still a beta...

let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide valid client_id as in the

> https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

the login with PayPal button is sending to below URI which contains client_id

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize?**client_id=eee5d94d000903b29b1263ae5654b369**&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20address%20https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes&redirect_uri=https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/access&nonce=05d0a60ee1f44361f449496505e05116&state=784d8bc3fe3a48a5105b4f8ddd8ae0e7