# I keep getting Validation Error: client_id provided in the request does not match any of the registered clients

Tags: android, oauth, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is driving me MAAAADDDD

I'm trying to implement "Log In With PayPal" on Android.

I'm using this sample app to try to get the login screen to show up. https://github.com/SeraphimSerapis/PayPal-Access-Android-Example

I have created an app on the https://devportal.x.com/ website as instructed, I just want to use OAuth 2.0, I did all the settings, no luck.

Also, followed the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16199165/546439 i.e. created a seller account on developers.paypal and clearly chosen login with paypal access and credentials etc, still no luck

I don't even know whether I should get the credentials from x.com or paypal.com, each of them give the same options but they return different keys, I am so lost.

Please help.

**UPDATE: added auth URL I am sending**

all of these are not working

https://identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/authorize?client_id=AXbPkxDchMYBBAWn2UExvLytvvbJDDXn6u-9nWNgF_J7SZmwQkdDTwxHkuKe&scope=https://identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/profile/me&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Faccess.com%2Findex.php&response_type=code

https://identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/authorize?client_id=ATL6BhBqBYAwJnolhJDT04El5GtxxDzTMAQEb5kkCdZVDrMr_v5bWlPpw7nN&scope=https://identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/profile/me&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Faccess.com%2Findex.php&response_type=code

https://identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/authorize?client_id=6956fcaf5d9fb4bbea22af7ce7f4cc7a&scope=https://identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/profile/me&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Faccess.com%2Findex.php&response_type=code

Comment: client_id/secret you have from devportal.x.com are for your live paypal account. credentials created on developer.paypal.com are for the sandbox account. devportal.x.com interface will eventually be migrated over to developer.paypal.com.  If something's not working you should email tmesserschmidt@paypal.com, I am sure he will be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, still not working, I've added the auth URL in the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

This error meaning that you are sending wrong client_Id "or not sending it" within the URI asking for token which is sent to authorize URL /authorize?client_id={client_id}, please share your URI to check it.

> client_id string  Unique client identifier obtained through the
>   application registration process. Required.

from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Comment: Thanks @Bobo, still not working, I've added the auth URL in the question, please have a look

Comment: are you sure that these client_ids are existed on the authorization server of paypal it seams it is not existed on the authorization server of paypal, if you can not define your client Id ask paypal support to provide it to you

Comment: I have raised a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Support, for the time being, have you implemented this before ? where did you get the client_id from ?

Comment: Actually I developed the provider and client before so that I'm aware about OAuth 2.0 mechanism you can find source code here https://github.com/bassemZohdy/Spring_REST_OAuth_Demo

Comment: oh ok, brillaint work thanks, but I'm looking for login with paypal

Comment: it is using OAuth 2.0 as in the URL I provide https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/ so it is standard and you can use same client, or any other OAuth 2.0 client like the one in Spring-Social project

Answer (score 1):

I stumpled across a similar problem. I already hat an REST app running and tried to implement PayPal Login. Everytime I tried to use the sandbox client_id I got the same error message as you.

Took me some time to figure out, that, in my own stupidity, I tried to call

```
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize
```

instead of

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize
```

Now everything works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue, I know this is a old issue and my solution may not be of much help. But I felt like sharing my fix.

I use devise for authentication and I wanted to implement PayPal login.

I configured omniauth for paypal inside config/initializers/devise.rb file. But by default the authentication path was "https://www.paypal.com/". As @Ello mentioned in his answer we need "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/" url path for sandbox.

Then I figured out that we can change the url path to sandbox by passing sandbox as true in omniauth configuration.

So this is what I did in devise config file to resolve the issue

```
config.omniauth :paypal, PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, PAYPAL_APP_SECRET, scope: PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS, sandbox: true
```